# how do i create a keyboard shortcut to upload a specific lambda function in vsCode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I'm new to vsCode and want to streamline some basic workflows related to Lambda functions. For example, I want to create a keyboard shortcut to update "TestFunction." To do this today I have to:

- Select the AWS Explorer extension in the left bar
- Navigate in the Explorer bar to "TestFunction"
- Right click "FirstFunction"
- Select "Upload Lambda."
- This brings me to a dialog to "select upload type" and allows me to choose between 'ZIP Archive' and 'Directory.' I want to select 'Directory'
- This brings up a Finder dialog. I then navigate to the folder that holds the files for "TestFunction" and select this folder
- This brings up a dialog that asks me to "Build Directory?" I select No
- This brings up a confirmation dialog that says "This will immediately publish the selected code as the $LATEST version of Lambda: firstFunction. Continue?" I select yes

After going through these steps, the Lambda function is uploaded and deployed. I'd like to do this with a simple keyboard shortcut. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is all this GUI stuff done in VSC API? If yes can you supply a command in the extension with arguments to bypass all the GUI stuff

Comment: if by 'GUI stuff' you mean that i'm interacting with the GUI, then yes. Would you mind explaining how to supply a command in the way you describe and bind to keyboard shortcut?

Comment: a link to the used extension would be helpful

Comment: i have 1) aws toolkit extension, and 2) aws CLI installed